# Angular 2 pipe error on filtering array of objects

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a search bar to search for items in array of objects but i get this error and i don't know how to fix it here is the error

ERROR TypeError: itemsArr.search is not a function ItemsComponent.html:5 
    at SearchPipe.transform (search.pipe.ts:11)

this is my html where i use the pipe

```
    <form id="searchBar">
    <label>Search</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="productName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</form>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Nr.</td>
        <td>Prekės pavadinimas</td>
        <td>Svoris gramais</td>
        <td>Kaina eur</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of itemsArr | search:productName"> 
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.weight }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td><button class="btn" (click)="addToShopCart(item)"> Pasirinkti </button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and here is my pipe code

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(itemsArr: any, productName: any): any {

    if (productName === undefined) return itemsArr;
      return itemsArr.search(function(item){
        return item.name.toLowerCase().includes(productName.toLowerCase());
      })

  }
}
```

Comment: search doesnt exist on js/ts arrays

Comment: how can i filter it than ?

Comment: well what youre doing would never work, youre telling the pipe to return item.name, not an object so it would still error

Comment: `.filter` instead of `.search`

Comment: @AyushGupta thanks u saved me ! it works :)